# [actionlib] Problems when try to connect client <=> server

Tags: navigation, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,
since 2 day working with my code I found what is causing troubles.
I cannot establish a working connection between a client and move_base server.
Since my code is really huge I m going to report here just the interesting part which is a sintetic version of my code.

```
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>
#include <actionlib/client/terminal_state.h>

#include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseAction.h>
#include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseGoal.h>

//######################## ACTIONLIB #################################################
/* Here the function used to reach the and keep track of the goals                  */
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;

/* Definitions of variables for the goal positions */
move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal_;

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

    ros::init( argc, argv, "pelican_driver" );

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::NodeHandle nh_private( "~" );


    MoveBaseClient ac_( "move_base", true );

    //######################## ACTIONLIB #################################################
    /* The server connection for the actionlib must be checked for 60 [sec] before going on... */
    ROS_INFO( "Checking the reply from the server..." );
    if( ac_.isServerConnected() ) 
        ROS_INFO( "Connected!" );
    if( !ac_.isServerConnected( ) ) 
        ROS_INFO( "Not connected" );      <= I GET ALL THE TIME "NOT CONNECTED"

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

2 Words more: my code works perfectly when I uncomment the line with `waitForServer` and I play with the whole code since weeks. Uncommenting that line it stucks literally on the above line and doesn't work anymore. It stops the created classes (which have a timer inside to run some program at a given loop), resulting in the fatidic

> [ WARN] [1412682893.011742911]:
> Waiting on transform from base_link to
> map to become available before running
> costmap, tf error: Could not find a
> connection between 'map' and
> 'base_link' because they are not part
> of the same tree.Tf has two or more
> unconnected trees.

(furthermore this is interesting for all the people looking for the reason they get that error. In my case the reason is quite simple: stucking at that point my code is not able to publish the transformation odom => base_link. So check this if you have to deal with).

Again: commenting that single line of code, my code works like a charm and all tf transformations/trees are identified as you can see in the following figure:

[image: image description]

Since my code is really quite a copy of this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals), I cannot find any solution to get rid of this problem.
In my launch file I start at first the driver of my robot (the code above honestly speaking), then the map_server and then the move_base

```
<launch>

    <!-- Launch the driver of the robot -->
    <include file="$(find quadrotor)/launch/robot_driver.launch" />

    <!-- Launch map_server with a blank map -->
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find quadrotor)/maps/blank_map.yaml" />

    <!-- Launch move_base and load all navigation parameters -->
    <include file="$(find quadrotor)/launch/move_base.launch" />

    <!-- Run a static transform between /odom and /map -->
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_map_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100" />

</launch>
```

I ve tried to invert the order without success.
What should I now do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194379/%5Bactionlib%5D-problems-when-try-to-connect-client-%3C=%3E-server/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Immediate steps:

- Try removing that weird while loop, just use ac.waitForServer() if you want to block until a connection is made. While loop without a code block is ambiguous, though I'm not sure if could lead to undefined behaviour.
- You should not be running both the static transform and the fake_localization, they are doing the same thing.

That should guarantee the map-> odom transform should be working. I'm guessing your robot_driver is providing odom -> base_link, and you've tested that that is working correctly.

Now, which node is running the above MoveClient code? Just want to make sure it's not interfering with your robot_driver in any way.

Also, can you connect and issue goals to *move_base* using the handy dandy debug tool `rosrun actionlib axclient.py /move_base`?

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-07**:
Thanks Paul. I ve updated the topics and tried all your suggestions (see code above again). No one works.
But you have arose an interesting question. Which node? The same as my robot_driver. The driver and MoveClient are under the same node Is that the problem?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-07**:
Yes, that will be a problem, especially if you're running everything as one thread. You could potentially multi-thread, but to do it the ROS way you should isolate functionality to nodes.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-07**:
Traditionally the driver node will at most subscribe to movement commands and publish odometry information .

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-07**:
Also, a clean way to post your whole drive node would be using http://gist.github.com

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-07**:
Paul was right... Never start driver and actionlib under the same node.
After I separated both file and respective classes the client get connected with the server.

Paul for president

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-07**:
good idea, but I may not publish the code due to (my) copyrights. At least not yet!